# How to change object into array

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I need to change into an array. What is the best approach?

```
var x = {
    vehicle: {
      manufacturer: "Volkswagen",
      carlineName: "Golf",
    }
}
```

I want the following result

```
var x = {
  vehicle: [
    {
      manufacturer: "Volkswagen",
      carlineName: "Golf",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `x.vehicle = [x.vehicle]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example, you can write:

```js
var x = {
    vehicle: {
      manufacturer: "Volkswagen",
      carlineName: "Golf",
    }
}

x.vehicle = [x.vehicle]

console.log(x)
```

`x.vehicle` gets

```
{
  manufacturer: "Volkswagen",
  carlineName: "Golf",
}
```

and the square brackets **[**`x.vehicle`**]** place that value into an array:

```
[{
  manufacturer: "Volkswagen",
  carlineName: "Golf",
}]
```

We want to reassign x.vehicle with this new value, so we use `x.vehicle = [x.vehicle]`

Answer (score 0):

You just build a new object wrapping your property in `[` and `]` to make it an array.

```js
var x = {
    vehicle: {
      manufacturer: "Volkswagen",
      carlineName: "Golf",
    }
}

var output = {
  vehicle: [x.vehicle] 
};

console.log(output);
```

This might be safer than mutating the existing object.